# GDPR - access to transaction data

Tags: gdpr, payment

Is it within my rights as a user of a payment service like Paypal or Western Union, to ask for the full details of a transaction that I did (namely the card number of the recipient) ?

edited : bank account -> card number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Payment service regulations, not GDPR

I do not think that GDPR is the appropriate legal act for this goal, instead you should look at your rights regarding the payment process as such. They should be specified in your contract with your payment service provider ("Paypal or Western Union"), however, they all should be similar with respect to these rights as for example, the Payment Services Directive (PSD 2, EU Directive  2015/2366) Article 57 requires the payment service provider to provide the payer all kinds of information on the individual transactions.

Answer (score 1):

If the receiving account is not your account, then information about it is not your personal information, so the GDPR right to view your PI held by the data controller would not apply, I believe. It may well be that the payment service would provide this information, but I dion't thin k that the GDPR would require it to do so. Some other law might also apply, however.

Comment: So if this information is considered as the personal information of someone else, why do classic banks provide this kind of information when asked ?  Are they not GDPR compliant ?

Comment: @Wondering I can't be sure, but I strongly suspect this is considered to fall under one of the other lawful bases of the GDPR.  Or it may be that bnks have not yet change older procedures to be compliant.

Comment: Another thing that let me a bit surprised, is how contradictory everything is : If this information is considered as personal information, why do payment services also let in clear the full name (which absolutely allows you to identify your beneficiary, and thus can be considered as personal data), and yet take the trouble to hide from you their bank account.

Comment: Reason why I say this, is because so far, their data privacy team refused giving me the information on the ground that it was my beneficiary personal data. However if they can't make me happy I will for sure point out this inconsistency to my national Data Protection Authority :( (although it may very well result in nothing, but who knows).

Comment: Basically what I think is :  either they should show me nothing or they should show  me everything. But it can not be in between and still be GDPR compliant. But as you say, there might be some other law of GDPR that eludes me..

Comment: "*either they should show me nothing or they should show me everything. But it can not be in between and still be GDPR compliant. *" I am fairly sure that is not correct. There may be good reasons to shoe you some but not all information about a transaction or about another person. Disclosing someone;'s bank account number might make it possible to make unauthorized withdrawals, while the name alone would not.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with it being personal data, but more with it being financial data. Still, this just mind-boggling that I do not have the right to know the destination of a transaction done with my own card. (if you are wondering, I had the bank account number in question, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to do this transaction in the first place, but I lost it ).

Answer (score 0):

If this is your personal data and no exception applies, then you are entitled to receive this information.

Personal data is any information that relates to an identifiable individual. In this context, you are identifiable. Since you initiated the transaction, information about transaction relates to you. Information about the recipient of the transaction could then also be your personal data.

There are exceptions to your right to access your personal data. In particular, you may be refused access if it would adversely affect the rights and freedoms of others (Art 15(4) GDPR). Here, we must consider the rights of the recipient, who is also a data subject of the transaction information.

So in general, GDPR does arguably requires these money transfer companies provide you information about your transactions. Even if the right to access wouldn't apply, they might have a legitimate interest in providing you this information, in which case the GDPR wouldn't prohibit this.

But you must consider whether the information you seek is in scope of the transaction. You're seeking information about the bank account number of the recipient. Yet, PayPal and Western Union do not transfer money between bank accounts. Indeed, one of the reasons to use such services is for privacy, in order to minimize which information is disclosed to the other party. Another reason is that neither PayPal nor Western Union require the recipient to have a linked bank account.

So you're seeking information that is out of scope for the transaction itself. Such additional information cannot be argued to be your personal data. Disclosing this information to you would breach the recipient's privacy, if that information even exists. In some reason, there might be a legitimate interest to get this data, for example if you were defrauded and need to obtain the recipient's identity in order to sue them. However, the money transfer service will have to weigh the interests of the involved people (including the service's own interests) and will likely decline such a request. But they will likely disclose necessary data when instructed so by a court order.

Comment: Thank you for you response. To be more exact what I'm seeking to obtain is not the bank account, but the card number of the transaction recipient. I did a VISA card to card transaction (which is a service provided by Western Union), and of course I was the one to provide both my card number and my recipient card number.